# Xamarin.Forms - How do I change the background color of the screen at random times?

Tags: android, xamarin, random, time, xamarin.forms

I'd like to change the background color of the screen at random times throughout the game level. For example, the player is playing the game on a white background for a couple seconds and then the background color changes to black and stays like that for 1 second, and then goes back to a white screen. Maybe a minute later the screen turns black, changes back to white, and then 2 seconds later it changes to black again.

Basically, how do I change the background color of the screen at random times?

Comment: backgroung color of **what** you want to change?

Comment: The background color of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Xamarin.Forms? This would be one approach to change the background color at random times, play around with the random values and timeSpan to get your desired rate.

EDIT: if you want the background to change on click and also at random times this is one approach.

```
    Random random = new Random();
    List<Color> colors = new List<Color>()
    {
        Color.Black,Color.White,Color.Red,Color.Blue
    };

    public AboutPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5), MaybeChangeBackground);
    }

    private bool MaybeChangeBackground()
    {
        if (random.Next(1, 5) == 4)
            ChangeToRandomBackground();
        return true;
    }

    private void Increment(object sender, EventArgs e) => ChangeToRandomBackground();

    private void ChangeToRandomBackground() => BackgroundColor = colors[random.Next(0, colors.Count+1)];
```

Comment: Thank you!! For the `Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5), ChangeBackground);` line, I put it into my own `TestPage()` function and it's fine, as well as everything else that I shifted around for my own function that was already being used. However, for your `ChangeBackground()` function, I shifted it into my own `private void Increment(object sender, EventArgs e)` function. How would I implement the code in your `ChangeBackground()` function into my own Increment function? I can update my post with sample codes of what I have if you would like?

Comment: The TimerAction needs to return a bool (true for continue the timer and false to stop it) and cannot have any arguments in the constructor, what is the reason that you want to treat it like a clicked-function? If you want the background to change on both a click and at random times you can make a private void ChangeBackground() where you put the if(random.Next(..... == 4) BackgroundColor = colors[...], and rename the ChangeBackground action to DoChangeBackground and call ChangeBackground() from there and from the button click function. Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Comment: Check my edited answer for it to always change on button click and still change at random times.